# How to use this.val in data parameter of jquery ajax function

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
$('input[name=id_num]').blur(function(){

$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "data_fetcher.php",
   data: "idnum= ' + this.val  + '",
   success: function(html){
     $("#results").append(html);
   }
 });    

});
```

My data_fetcher.php looks like this:

```
<?php


$idnum = $_POST['idnum'];
.....

?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the function is an event (`blur`) of the input, `this` inside the function will reference to the DOM Object `input`.

To access jQuery functions like `val()` you need to transform it in a jQuery object. To do this, just enclose `this` in a `$()` accessor: `$(this)`. This have the exact same result of `$('input[name=id_num]')`, but is faster since jQuery don't need to make the search on the object list.

The `data` line would then look like this:

```
data: "idnum=" + $(this).val(),
```

Also take care with single quotes/double quotes. In your original code the result for data would be the string "`idnum= ' + this.val  + '`". Single quotes enclosed by double quotes are included in the string and have no effect in splitting code area from string area.